# Add new row into the datagrid when last row is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid, which has 4 columns in it. I binded a collection to the DataGrid.
Here is my XAML:

```
 <dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 RowHeight="27"
                 CanUserAddRows="True">
        <dg:DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                             Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
            </Style>
        </dg:DataGrid.Resources>
        <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn  Header="Product Name"
                                    Binding="{Binding ProductName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    Width="250"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn  Header="Unit Price"
                                    Binding="{Binding UnitPrice,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                    Width="130"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn  Header="Qty"
                                    Binding="{Binding Quantity,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                    Width="130"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn  Header="Amount"
                                    Binding="{Binding Amount,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    Width="130"/>
        </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
    </dg:DataGrid>
```

My requirement is, I want to create a new row when we select the last row on the DataGrid.
I tried to add a new row like this:

```
DataGrid.Items.Add(new DataItem()); // add a row
```

but this will create the row by initializing the data item with the default values. I want to create a new row without using the new `DataItem`,How do I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have set `CanUserAddRows="True"` so you will automatically get one blank row (NewItemPlaceHolder) always. Why you want another row?

Comment: @RohitVats ,I use the datagrid for data entry when the user enter first row ,I want to provide an new row for the user to enter new item

Comment: When you select last row and commit the row (by pressing enter on editable cell of any row), you automatically get new row. You don't need to add it manually.

Comment: @RohitVats, actually I dont want to use the enter key inside the datagrid, I would like to navigate through the datagrid by using the tab key when the last cell of last row is reached then pressing the tab key , I want to create a new row

Comment: I think you are looking for a custom behaviour i.e. you have bound your itemssource to data object and you want new row to be added only to view when empty (on tab or enter) but I guess you would want it to be added to bound itemssource once user starts filling the data